# Linq with data Error condition ( 'Date' is not supported in LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using a LINQ statement to get some data from the table based on data value:

```
var oDay = diabeticDB.user_data
                     .Where(y => y.date >= DateTime.Now.Date
                            & y.BG != null
                            & y.userid == u)
                     .Average(x => x.BG).Value;
```

I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression contained in `Where(...)` is converted to SQL, and the EF query provider (that does this conversion) does not understand `DateTime.Now.Date`.

The expression can contain a specific value, though - so create a local variable for today's date and use that:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

var oDay = diabeticDB.user_data
    .Where(y => y.date >= today & y.BG != null & y.userid == u)
    .Average(x => x.BG).Value;
```

Comment: that is *not* a constant.

Comment: @DanielA.White The value as used in the expression is a constant in terms of the expression tree, not in terms of being the same value every time.

Comment: @CharlesMager You're right but it's still a tad misleading to use that word.

Comment: Thanks both - I've reworded to avoid the confusion!